# How to setup concourse without access to the Internet?

Tags: concourse

I've got an internal docker registry, internal DNS, etc. Access to the larger Internet is blocked except http/https via a proxy, which I'd like to avoid anyway. UDP calls to 8.8.8.8 are also blocked, in case you're wondering. I'm trying to set 2.7.0 up on Ubuntu 16.04, but the simplest hello world tutorial just hangs.

Comment: What error are you seeing, is your job stuck in a `pending` state?

Comment: turns out that for whatever reason running it via docker and not just the downloaded binaries was enough - properly configured tasks with a private repository work fine now.

i've noticed that there's a few settings that can be changed but changing them breaks the system, e.g. workdir on the worker must be the default or there are weird runc errors; web port must be 8080 or else worker registration doesn't work.